# Printing problem Mathematica v12

Tags: system

After installing MMA v12 (Windos 7) I cannot print (using `Print`) on several printers, which work fine together with other programs.

If a use `PrintPreview` printing works.

Any idea how to resolve this problem are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If previewing the print works, does it work to print into a PDF? And if the answer is yes, does it work to print *that* PDF?

Comment: @halirutan Thanks! I can save to pdf and print this pdf!

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't solve the underlying mystery why you cant print directly.